# Accessing a child table from a parent table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, models, controllers

I have two table: `bids` and `credit_operations`.
In my models I have;

bid.rb:              `has_one :credit_operation`

credit_operation.rb  `belongs_to :bid`

In credit_operation table I have `bid_id` column.
How can I access some attributes in the `credit_operations` table from `bids_controller.rb`?

Comment: Did you try `bid.credit_operation`. Note that its singular.

Answer (score 0):

to help others: The error was being produced because there was an empty attribute in the field than I was accessing.

meaning `bid.credit_operation` could not work.
but testing first made it work. so I used:

```
bid.creditoperation_id ? bid.creditoperation.name : ""
```

testing first if it is present, if true then `bid.creditoperation.name` is returned, otherwise returns empty